# Does jdbc support persian language

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

I designed a java desktop application using jdbc technology to connect to mysql database.
But when I want to store a data in my db which is in persian language it saved like some `????`

I tried creating the database with both

```
CREATE DATABASE 'db' CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE  `Table1` (
[...]) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

I tried every other COLLATEs but they seem not working properly.

What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you insert some persian via MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Its ok! I work with Navicat and when insert persian text via this software there isn't any problem. I think problem is in connecting to db! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the driver properties are set.  Check that `useUnicode` is `true`, `characterEncoding` is "UTF-8".  I assume you are using the Connector/J JDBC driver.

Comment: yes I'm using JDBC Connector driver,but excuse me where can i change this settings??

Comment: I Use this codes:
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", USERNAME, PASSWORD);

Comment: Please, just read the documentation for the [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) driver.  You can add those properties to the connection URL.

Comment: I found the solution as you see:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ictrc_db?characterEncoding=UTF-8", USERNAME, PASSWORD);

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112961/getting-question-marks-when-inserting-hebrew-characters-into-a-mysql-table#14116277). 
A brief version of what the answer says is that you should add

```
?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

To the end of JDBC connection URL.
For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```